# tableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation while changing Number of Rows

Tags: ios, tableview, reloaddata

Whenever I run reloadSections:withRowAnimation it crashes because the number of rows in the section changed (the underlying data changed which is why I'm wanting to reload the section).  Is there a good way to reload section and tell it to update row heights via

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and to update number of rows?

I basically want to run a [tableView reloadData] without updating all the sections, just one... and I still want numberOfRows for the section to run and the row height which doesn't run with updateSections.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

I get the error which I know why it's being caused as described above:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Show the relevant code for doing the reload.

Comment: are you inserting any rows anywhere in code

Comment: No I'm not, a new option would be to figure out my row count, then insert rows appropriately or delete them, but that still doesn't update the height of existing rows.